# Lower bounding a term of the form $(x^k -1)^s$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I have a term of the form $(x^k -1)^s$ and I would like to find a nice looking lower bound for it without any additive terms inside of the parentheses. The reason to that is because I want something which is nice to exponentiate later.

How could I go about this? I need to find an inequality of the form:

$(x^k -1)^s \geq \hat{x}^{ks}$.
And we know the following about the parameters.

$x \geq 2$

$0 \leq k \leq 1$

$s$ strictly positive

Comment: try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: the exponent $s$ is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: In Bernoulli’s_inequality the exponent can be [generalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Generalization) to an arbitrary real number.